# Are states required to divide into congressional districts?

Tags: united-states, voting-districts

It seems as though there are myriad other voting schemes that do not require representatives to run for a "district".  For example, representatives for the state could all be on the ballot for the entire state, and the top **n** in the state (where **n** is the number of available seats) get seats.

Do all multi-member states draw districts?  If so, are they required to do so?  If not, then why do they not adopt other voting schemes?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Q: *Are states required to divide into congressional districts?*

Yes.

[2 U.S. Code § 2c](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/2/2c) - Number of Congressional Districts; number of Representatives from each District

> In each State entitled in the Ninety-first Congress or in any subsequent Congress thereafter to more than one Representative under an apportionment made pursuant to the provisions of section 2a(a) of this title, **there shall be established by law a number of districts equal to the number of Representatives to which such State is so entitled, and Representatives shall be elected only from districts so established, no district to elect more than one Representative** (except that a State which is entitled to more than one Representative and which has in all previous elections elected its Representatives at Large may elect its Representatives at Large to the Ninety-first Congress).

Occasionally, a bill will be introduced to change to multi-member districts. However, the bills are never brought to the floor for a vote. One such example is [H.R.3863](https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-bill/3863) - Fair Representation Act from the 117th Congress. That bill would have allowed for some states to have districts with three to five members. And, others to have up to six at-large members. It would have also also required ranked choice voting for "all elections for Senators and Members of the House of Representatives".

Comment: It should be noted that there's also a requirement, in states with a sufficiently high non-White populations, to create districts that ensure the election of racial minorities.

Comment: @dan04 this was why I asked, actually, since a number of non-district-based voting schemes would make that whole problem moot.  Viz, suppose the population is 70% X group and 30% Y group, and group X always votes party Xparty and never Yparty, group Y always votes Yparty never Xparty.  If there are 10 seats available, 20 candidates, 3 of which are Yparty and 7 of which are Xparty, then the seats will be divided 7 and 3, exactly along demographic lines.  Of course the real world is more complex, but the district-based system is probably the worst possible system for this problem.

Comment: For example, if the 10 districts above were created to include population uniformly at random, then in all probability 0 seats would go to Yparty.

Comment: That depends on how the voting is conducted.  If there are 10 completely independent at-large seats to be elected, in each of the 10 races the vote will be 70% X and 30% Y, and the outcome will be that there are ZERO seats going to Party Y; this is why we have districts.

Comment: @arp I don't think it has to work that way. If a state is entitled to eight seats in Congress, and there are 30 candidates on the ballot, just allow every voter to vote for as many candidates as they choose, from zero to 30, and the top eight are elected.

Comment: Does Congress have legitimate power to legislate on this? Consider my proposal in my comment above. Suppose a state legislature decided to do it that way. Would that not be within the powers of the legislature?

Comment: I might be misreading, and a court might not agree with this interpretation, but is there anything stopping a state from creating 10 overlapping districts, each of which is the size of the entire state? I don't see a requirement in the statue for districts to be non-overlapping.

Comment: @OscarSmith:  I think a court would be pretty skeptical of the argument "it's not one district with ten members, it's ten identical overlapping districts with one member each."  It seems too cute by half.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I think that the "vote for as many as you choose" scheme also ends up with 100% Xparty in the proposed example from my first comment above.

Comment: you could always pick 10 blocks (each zoned for industrial use so no one lives in them), each of which is excluded from one of the districts :)

Comment: @MichaelHardy If there's _n_ number of seats and people are allowed to vote for 0-_n_ candidates, then that doesn't improve anything.  Assume those 30 candidates are split 15/15.  15 of those people will each get 70% of the total votes each (and then have some kind of tie breaker to split up the 8 seats between them) and the other 15 will get 30% of the total votes each and get 0 seats.

Comment: Conversely, if people are only allowed to vote for 1 out of the _n_ candidates, then tactical voting becomes a **huge** issue, because a vote for one candidate from your party is a vote that's not for a different one, and every vote for the leading candidate that's more than the 2nd place person got is a wasted vote that could have gone towards someone else from the same party. The only way to make multi-member districts work is some form of party-based voting, where voters cast a single vote for a party which then wins some number of seats to divide up. That of course has its own problems.

Comment: @Bobson: [STV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_transferable_vote) can work without formal political parties, though counting the votes can get complicated.

Comment: Anyhow, proportional representation isn't well-known in the US.  Historically (especially in the White Democrat controlled Solid South), multi-member or at-large elections were used with *non*-proportional election methods, allowing the majority party to take *all* of the seats as in @arp's example.  Congress "fixed" the issue in 1967 by mandating single-member districts.

Comment: @arp Why do you speak of "each of the 10 races"? There could be only one race in which all of the candidates are on the ballot. Every voter votes for as many of the candidates as the voter chooses and the ones getting the most votes---as many as there are seat in Congress in that state---are elected.

Comment: "The only way to make multi-member districts work is some form of party-based voting."  This is a strong statement.  Could you cite any theoretical results that back this up a la Arrow's theorems?

Comment: Because, @MichaelHardy, there are many different ways to run an election, and often multiple at-large seats are, in fact, separate races.

Comment: @arp "Often". But not always and you just _assumed_ that that is what was meant.